# How to Count Number of in in a field

Tags: php, sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a data base named nominator which has some fields

it have a in field named *'noinatedUnder'* how can i show the number of inS to that field

this is the Raw text of 
**SELECT FROM Nominator**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#73:2",
            "@version": 2,
            "@class": "Nominator",
            "isTemp": "true",
            "id": "JJRXW",
            "Email": "testuser@test.com",
            "Name": "nijeesh",
            "Phone": "7894561234",
            "school": "#65:2",
            "in_noinatedUnder": [
                "#161:1",
                "#162:1",
                "#163:1",
                "#164:0",
                "#165:0",
                "#166:0",
                "#167:0",
                "#168:0",
                "#161:0",
                "#162:0",
                "#163:0"
            ],
            "@fieldTypes": "school=x,in_noinatedUnder=g"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#74:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Nominator",
            "isTemp": "true",
            "id": "SU7SV",
            "Email": "npms@school.com",
            "Name": "pon muthu",
            "Phone": "7778455215",
            "school": "#65:2",
            "@fieldTypes": "school=x"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#75:1",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Nominator",
            "isTemp": "true",
            "id": "4DZ86",
            "Email": "sivaraj@testschool.com",
            "Name": "sivaraj",
            "Phone": "7788899445",
            "school": "#65:2",
            "@fieldTypes": "school=x"
        },
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#76:1",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Nominator",
            "isTemp": "true",
            "id": "HFQJ1",
            "Email": "klndk@knvd.com",
            "Name": "dbhbsd",
            "Phone": "8656548745",
            "school": "#65:2",
            "@fieldTypes": "school=x"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 6.12 sec. Returned 4 record(s)"
}
```

in this on the first entry there is 11 entrys in the in->nominated under area and 0 on everything else  how to select this number using sql for each field

that is it should print

```
-----------
count |                                                                           ----------
11
0
0
0
```

i did got the result using php

```
    $query = "select * from `Nominator`";
    $result = runquery($query);
    $a = array();

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($result);$i++)
    {
    echo '<p>';
        echo isset($result[$i]->oData->in_noinatedUnder)?sizeof($result[$i]->oData->in_noinatedUnder):0;

    echo '</p>';
    }

function runquery($query)
{
    $client = new PhpOrient();
    $client->hostname = 'localhost';
    $client->port = 2424;
    $client->username = 'root';
    $client->password = 'hello';
    $client->connect();
    $client->dbOpen('tabe');


    $result = $client->query($query);



    $json = json_decode(json_encode($result));



    if (sizeof($json) > 0) {
        return $json;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

So is there any way to get the count directly from sql it self, like **select count(*) from nominator** gives count of nominators

Comment: And you have tried what? to solve your requirement!

Comment: Have you come across [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) yet in your travels

Comment: i have updated my answer please check

Comment: Ah, ok, but thats a question not an answer

Comment: Hi, let me see if I understood correctly, what you wanna retrive with the query is the number of "in_noinatedUnder", that in your case should be 11, am I right? Thx.

Comment: yes that is  what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of vertexes in in try this query:

```
select in().size() from <class-name>
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: THANK You That worked this is what i was looking for                                                 `select in('nominatedUnder').size() from Nominator`